# Is Pro Webmasters the right place to ask Web design questions?

Tags: discussion

I have a question about some css.  Do I post it here?  If not here, where?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [Doctype](http://doctype.com/). That site is targeted at web design questions, which aren't really webmaster-related.

Comment: Whoa wait a second... I've seen this happen before... is Doctype going to end up like UXExchange.com? (i.e. with a newer mainstream SE site replacing it in a few months)

Comment: @danlefree Doctype is not an SE site, although it has similarities. It is about web design, while this site is on webmastering - really two different things.

Answer (score 6):

I would actually suggest [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com). There are currently 23,946 questions tagged `css` and 31,479 tagged `html` so you'll certainly get good answers more quickly there.

If your question is less code-oriented and more management or "philosophical" related, it is perfectly fine to ask it here on Pro Webmasters.